# iOS crash: missing images before playing video

Tags: ios, video

I want to use MPMoviePlayerViewController to play a video, then it comes out a crash with following log:

*** Assertion failure in -[MPDetailSlider _setupControlsForStyle], /SourceCache/MediaPlayer_Sim/MobileMusicPlayer-1641.29/MPDetailSlider.m:708

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'missing images for style 2'

Did anyone meet this crash before, could you help? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This issue is fixed, it's due to an over-written internal method in iOS SDK: + (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name inBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem we had.  Thanks for adding the edit.  We had a category to UIImage that was called imageNamed:inBundle.  Changing the name to our category method solved the problem.